# How to map this response data into this format in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to map this response data coming from Woocommerce Rest API.

This is a snippet of the original Woocommerce Rest API response:

```
{
    number: "206"
    discount_tax: "0.00"
    discount_total: "380.00"
    meta_data {
        0 {
            id: 2928
            key: "is_vat_exempt"
            value: "no"
        }
        1 {
            id: 2929
            key: "att_info-94_1"
            value: "||CJ||Cortez||  ||||84||"
        }
        2 {
            id: 2930
            key: "_alternate_phone"
            value: "98765432"
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to transform it like this one.

```
{
    number: "206"
    discount_tax: "0.00"
    discount_total: "380.00"
    meta_data {
        is_vat_exempt: "no"
        att_info-94_1: "||CJ||Cortez||  ||||84||"
        _alternate_phone: "98765432"
    }
}
```

My Code:

```
public getFlightOrder() {
    var params = {status:'completed',};
    this.data_api.getflightOrder(params,this.passID.id)
        .pipe(
            map(responseData => {})
         )
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.bookingData = data;
        }
    );
}
```

As you can see there is no mapping yet as I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question doesn't really have anything to do with Angular 8 specifically but you can do something like this

```js
const data = {
    number: "206",
    discount_tax: "0.00",
    discount_total: "380.00",
    meta_data: [
        {
            id: 2928,
            key: "is_vat_exempt",
            value: "no"
        },
        {
            id: 2929,
            key: "att_info-94_1",
            value: "||CJ||Cortez||  ||||84||"
        },
        {
            id: 2930,
            key: "_alternate_phone",
            value: "98765432"
        }
    ]
}

data.meta_data = Object.assign({}, ...data.meta_data.map(x => ({[x.key]: x.value})));

console.log(data);
```

**EDIT**

As per your question you can do the following

```
public getFlightOrder() {
  var params = {status:'completed',};
  this.data_api.getflightOrder(params,this.passID.id)
    .subscribe((data) => {
      this.bookingData = {
        ...data, meta_data: Object.assign({}, ...data.meta_data.map(x => ({[x.key]: x.value})))
      };
    });
}
```

Comment: What a beautiful one-liner

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
const data = {
    number: "206",
    discount_tax: "0.00",
    discount_total: "380.00",
    meta_data: [
        {
            id: 2928,
            key: "is_vat_exempt",
            value: "no"
        },
        {
            id: 2929,
            key: "att_info-94_1",
            value: "||CJ||Cortez||  ||||84||"
        },
        {
            id: 2930,
            key: "_alternate_phone",
            value: "98765432"
        }
    ]
}

const newData = {
  ...data,
  meta_data: data.meta_data.map((item) => ({[item.key]: item.value}))
};
```